# bad int8 external representation"VM000141210"

Tags: unix, netezza, ab-initio

While running an ab-initio PSET I'm getting the error like: "bad int8 external representation"VM000141210"". What the pset does is take data from different source tables and loads into target table with transformations. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of ab-initio, but in other ETL tools you can receive similar error messages if the meta data inside the tool is different from that of the target table itself.
Could it be that this particular PSET command is dependent on all columns being filled out, and in the same order as they occur in the database?

Write back with more specifics if you need more help...

- what data types are in play?
- what do you see if you stage data in a file instead?
- if you apply filters on the source, can you the make the session succeed (binary search)?